# Is $(\pmb{b}^\mathrm{T}\pmb{x})^2=\pmb{b}^\mathrm{T}(\pmb{x}\pmb{x}^T)\pmb{b}$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, outer-product

Let $\pmb{b}$ and $\pmb{x}$ be two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then:
$$(\pmb{b}^\mathrm{T}\pmb{x})^2=(\pmb{b}^\mathrm{T}\pmb{x})(\pmb{b}^\mathrm{T}\pmb{x})=(\pmb{b}^\mathrm{T}\pmb{x})(\pmb{x}^\mathrm{T}\pmb{b})$$
Now, is $(\pmb{b}^\mathrm{T}\pmb{x})(\pmb{x}^\mathrm{T}\pmb{b})=\pmb{b}^\mathrm{T}(\pmb{x}\pmb{x}^T)\pmb{b}$ true? I cannot find a counterexample, but I wonder what property it is.

Comment: It is true, by associativity of matrix multiplication.

Comment: yes because matrix multiplication is associative

Comment: Associativity is key but also note that this works because every real $1\times 1$ matrix is symmetric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is true. It is simply a consequence of the associativity of matrix multiplication:

$$ (AB)(CD) = A(BC)D $$

Here, think of $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ as $n \times 1$ matrices, and take $A = \mathbf{b}^T$, $B = \mathbf{x}$, $C = \mathbf{x}^T$, and $D = \mathbf{b}$.

Comment: I was confused because the inner product is not associative like matrix multiplication.

Comment: @s1m0n3 Matrix multiplication is associative, and the inner product is a special case of matrix multiplication (where you multiply a $1 \times n$ matrix with an $n \times 1$ matrix), so it inherits the associativity.

Comment: You may be confused because, in general, $\mathbf{a} (\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c}) \ne (\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}) \mathbf{c}$. But notice that this equation mixes two different types of product: the _inner product_ $\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c}$ and the _scalar product_ $\alpha \mathbf{x}$. In the case of $\mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{b}$, there is no such mixing; all of the products involved are matrix products, so everything can be freely re-associated.